# Is there a way to access all of a page's components?

Tags: sxa, scriban

I want to create a custom scriban Processor and I need to access all of the renderings that have been put on the page. Is there a way to access that data?

Comment: You have an access to the context item there. You can get all the renderings from an item presentation. Did you try it already?

Comment: I have not. I will look into that, thanks.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I am new to Sitecore and Scriban. How do access the renderings that way?

Comment: You are new to Sitecore and you want to do such things? Something is wrong here... What is your goal? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I just want to access the ID from the rendering parameters of each component that is added to my page layout.

Comment: @Danny, so you have a variant and using Scriban you want to go through all renderings on the context item to access rendering parameters for each rendering; what is this for? maybe there is an easier way.

Comment: Exactly, why you need some IDs from other component's rendering parameters? That is not something usual...

Comment: I wanted to create a custom processor that would go through the rendering parameters of all of the components added to the layout of the current page. I wanted to dynamically create in page navigation by grabbing those ids.